# java script overflow (window.btoa) uploading file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to upload files into CRM using javascript and the CRM's js sdk.
It works fine for small files but when I try to upload large file (not too much 25mb) the code throws an overflow exception. It happens when I convert the file to base 64 string. following is the code sample:

```
function _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) { // Convert Array Buffer to Base 64 string
        try
        {
            var binary = '';
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
            var len = bytes.byteLength;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
            }
            return window.btoa(binary);
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            alert(e.message);
        }

    }
```

following is the line which throws the exception:

```
return window.btoa(binary);
```

Anybody can help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Guess you could split the input into parts, base64-encode them individually, and then concatenate the encoded parts together again. As long as you split it into multiples of 3 bytes, the end result will be the same.